# How to programmatically generate a client authentication certificate

Tags: java, ssl

I want to made a web site that lets the end users generate a cert that they can authentication with.
I was able to create a client authentication certificate with openssl with these commands.

```
#Make client ssl cert.
CLIENT_PASSWORD="password"
CLIENT_ALIAS="client"

touch ./client.cnf
echo "
[ req ]
prompt = no
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
output_password = $CLIENT_PASSWORD

[ req_distinguished_name ]
localityName           = "L" # L=
organizationName       = "O" # O=
organizationalUnitName = "OU" # OU=
commonName             = "CN" # CN=
" > ./client.cnf

openssl req -config client.cnf -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout client.key -out client.csr
openssl ca -keyfile ca.key -cert ca.crt -out client.crt -policy policy_anything -days 3650 -batch -passin pass:$CLIENT_PASSWORD -infiles client.csr
openssl pkcs12 -export -in client.crt -inkey client.key -out client.p12 -passin pass:$CLIENT_PASSWORD -passout pass:$CLIENT_PASSWORD -name $CLIENT_ALIAS
```

I found the Bouncy Castle library v1.5, I found a few examples. I put this together, but it's not making a usable cert.

```
private static void MakeP12() throws Exception {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

    String sigName = "SHA1withRSA";

    KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC");

    kpg.initialize(2048);

    KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();

    X500NameBuilder x500NameBld = new X500NameBuilder(BCStyle.INSTANCE);

    x500NameBld.addRDN(BCStyle.C, "AU");
    x500NameBld.addRDN(BCStyle.ST, "Victoria");
    x500NameBld.addRDN(BCStyle.L, "Melbourne");
    x500NameBld.addRDN(BCStyle.O, "The Legion of the Bouncy Castle");

    X500Name subject = x500NameBld.build();

    PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder requestBuilder = new JcaPKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder(subject, kp.getPublic());

    ExtensionsGenerator extGen = new ExtensionsGenerator();

    extGen.addExtension(Extension.subjectAlternativeName, false, new GeneralNames(new GeneralName(GeneralName.rfc822Name, "feedback-crypto@bouncycastle.org")));

    requestBuilder.addAttribute(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.pkcs_9_at_extensionRequest, extGen.generate());

    PKCS10CertificationRequest req1 = requestBuilder.build(new JcaContentSignerBuilder(sigName).setProvider("BC").build(kp.getPrivate()));

    if (req1.isSignatureValid(new JcaContentVerifierProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC").build(kp.getPublic())))
    {
        System.out.println(sigName + ": PKCS#10 request verified.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(sigName + ": Failed verify check.");
    }

    PKCS10CertificationRequest csr = req1;




    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("D:/Sun/certs/ca.jks");
    KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    keystore.load(is, "password".toCharArray());

    PrivateKey cakey = (PrivateKey)keystore.getKey("my_ca", "password".toCharArray());
    X509Certificate cacert = (X509Certificate)keystore.getCertificate("my_ca");

    AlgorithmIdentifier sigAlgId = new DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder().find("SHA1withRSA");
    AlgorithmIdentifier digAlgId = new DefaultDigestAlgorithmIdentifierFinder().find(sigAlgId);
    X500Name issuer = new X500Name(cacert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName());
    BigInteger serial = new BigInteger(32, new SecureRandom());
    Date from = new Date();

    int validity = 1;
    Date to = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (validity * 86400000L));

    X509v3CertificateBuilder certgen = new X509v3CertificateBuilder(issuer, serial, from, to, csr.getSubject(), csr.getSubjectPublicKeyInfo());
    certgen.addExtension(X509Extension.basicConstraints, false, new BasicConstraints(false));
    certgen.addExtension(X509Extension.subjectKeyIdentifier, false, new SubjectKeyIdentifier(csr.getSubjectPublicKeyInfo()));
    certgen.addExtension(X509Extension.authorityKeyIdentifier, false, new AuthorityKeyIdentifier(new GeneralNames(new GeneralName(new X509Name(cacert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName()))), cacert.getSerialNumber()));

    ContentSigner signer = new BcRSAContentSignerBuilder(sigAlgId, digAlgId).build(PrivateKeyFactory.createKey(cakey.getEncoded()));
    X509CertificateHolder holder = certgen.build(signer);

    /*===========================================================================*/

    PKCS12SafeBagBuilder eeCertBagBuilder = new JcaPKCS12SafeBagBuilder(new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider( "BC" ).getCertificate( holder ));
    eeCertBagBuilder.addBagAttribute(PKCS12SafeBag.friendlyNameAttribute, new DERBMPString("Eric's Key"));

    JcaX509ExtensionUtils extUtils = new JcaX509ExtensionUtils();
    SubjectKeyIdentifier pubKeyId = extUtils.createSubjectKeyIdentifier(kp.getPublic());
    eeCertBagBuilder.addBagAttribute(PKCS12SafeBag.localKeyIdAttribute, pubKeyId);

    OutputEncryptor encOut = new JcePKCSPBEOutputEncryptorBuilder(NISTObjectIdentifiers.id_aes256_CBC).setProvider("BC").build(JcaUtils.KEY_PASSWD);
    PKCS12SafeBagBuilder keyBagBuilder = new JcaPKCS12SafeBagBuilder(kp.getPrivate(), encOut);

    keyBagBuilder.addBagAttribute(PKCS12SafeBag.friendlyNameAttribute, new DERBMPString("Eric's Key"));
    keyBagBuilder.addBagAttribute(PKCS12SafeBag.localKeyIdAttribute, pubKeyId);

    PKCS12PfxPduBuilder builder = new PKCS12PfxPduBuilder();
    builder.addData(keyBagBuilder.build());
    builder.addEncryptedData(new JcePKCSPBEOutputEncryptorBuilder(
            PKCSObjectIdentifiers.pbeWithSHAAnd128BitRC2_CBC).setProvider("BC").build(JcaUtils.KEY_PASSWD), 
            new PKCS12SafeBag[]{eeCertBagBuilder.build()});

    PKCS12PfxPdu pfx = builder.build(new JcePKCS12MacCalculatorBuilder(NISTObjectIdentifiers.id_sha256), JcaUtils.KEY_PASSWD);

    readPKCS12File(pfx, "password".toCharArray());
    /*===========================================================================*/

}
```

It's also not giving me consistent error message.

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCSException: unable to read encrypted data: failed to construct sequence from byte[]: DER length more than 4 bytes: 79
    at org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.decryptPrivateKeyInfo(Unknown Source)
    at cwguide.JcePKCS12Example.readPKCS12File(JcePKCS12Example.java:272)
    at cwguide.JcePKCS12Example.MakeP12(JcePKCS12Example.java:211)
    at cwguide.JcePKCS12Example.main(JcePKCS12Example.java:81)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: failed to construct sequence from byte[]: DER length more than 4 bytes: 79
    at org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more

Exception in thread "main" org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCSException: unable to read encrypted data: unknown object in getInstance: org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERApplicationSpecific
    at org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.decryptPrivateKeyInfo(Unknown Source)
    at cwguide.JcePKCS12Example.readPKCS12File(JcePKCS12Example.java:272)
    at cwguide.JcePKCS12Example.MakeP12(JcePKCS12Example.java:211)
    at cwguide.JcePKCS12Example.main(JcePKCS12Example.java:81)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown object in getInstance: org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERApplicationSpecific
    at org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more

Exception in thread "main" org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCSException: unable to read encrypted data: failed to construct sequence from byte[]: unknown tag 41 encountered
    at org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCS8EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.decryptPrivateKeyInfo(Unknown Source)
    at cwguide.JcePKCS12Example.readPKCS12File(JcePKCS12Example.java:272)
    at cwguide.JcePKCS12Example.MakeP12(JcePKCS12Example.java:211)
    at cwguide.JcePKCS12Example.main(JcePKCS12Example.java:81)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: failed to construct sequence from byte[]: unknown tag 41 encountered
    at org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

I have read many Q/A on this site that have help me, but the answer still eludes me.

Comment: So you're kindly generating a key pair for the client. So the private key isn't private, it is known to both you and the client. So it is completely and utterly invalid for the purpose you intend it for. You need to completely rethink this. The *client* should provide the keypair, generated, somehow, at his end.

Comment: Maybe I could get the web browser to generate the key with some java script on the client side.

Comment: The private key must be not only generated at the client side but saved at the client side in a file that is accessed by OpenSSL or JSSE or whatever SSL system you're planning for the client to use and authenticate over. The certificate is of zero use without it.

Comment: Yes I understand that part of it, the .p12 file contains the cert and the private key.  You also have to encrypt the .p12 for Firefox to accept it in SSL storage.  But if I can't get this example to work how will I get any SSL code to work?

Comment: If getting your SSL code to work involves solving the problem of supplying a client certificate, and you can't solve *that* problem, you can't solve the problem of getting your SSL code to work. But inventing an unsecure workaround that leaks private keys doesn't constitute solving the problem either. If the clients don't have valid SSL certificates that are trusted by the server, *that's* the problem you need to solve. Not just 'how to programmatically generate a client authentication certificate'. That question alone doesn't begin to solve the actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I reworked my last answer to use Bouncy Castle v1.5 in place of OpenSSL.  It took a lot of googling to find non-deprecated functions from Bouncy Castle.  I still used a Keygen HTML5 tag, to generate the private key for Firefox.  I was only interested in using Firefox, but from what I read most other web browser should work. If you use this code make sure you set a different serial-number for each cert if you try to import two with the name number; Firefox just ignores the request.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.cert.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import org.bouncycastle.asn1.misc.*;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.*;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.*;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Extension;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.*;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.*;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.netscape.*;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.*;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.*;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.*;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.*;

public class ExampleClientAuth extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5599842503981845987L;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>SSL Generator</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");

        out.println("<form method=\"post\">");
        out.println("<keygen name=\"pubkey\" challenge=\"randomchars\">");
        out.println("Username: <input type=\"text\" name=\"username\" value=\"John Doe\">");
        out.println("<input type=\"submit\" name=\"createcert\" value=\"Generate\">");
        out.println("</form>");

        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");     
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String CN = "/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/certs/";
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(CN+"log.txt", "UTF-8");
        try {
            response.setContentType("application/x-x509-user-cert");
            OutputStream os=response.getOutputStream();
            String pubkey = request.getParameter("pubkey");
            pubkey = pubkey.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "").replace("\t", "").replace("\0", "").replace("\u000B", "");
            String username = request.getParameter("username");

            BC_SingCert_Spkac(os,pubkey,username,out);

            os.close();
            os.flush();         
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace(out);
        } finally {
            out.close();
            out.flush();
        }
    }

    protected void BC_SingCert_Spkac(OutputStream os,String Spkac, String ID, PrintWriter log) throws Exception {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keystore.load(new FileInputStream("/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/cacerts.jks"),
            "password".toCharArray());
        PrivateKey cakey = (PrivateKey)keystore.getKey("my_ca", "password".toCharArray());
        X509Certificate cacert = (X509Certificate)keystore.getCertificate("my_ca");

        X509Certificate ncert = createCertFromSpkac(cacert, cakey, Spkac, ID);

        byte[] buf = ncert.getEncoded();
        os.write(buf, 0, buf.length);
    }

    private X509Certificate createCertFromSpkac(X509Certificate cacert,
        PrivateKey caPrivKey, String spkacData, String ID) throws Exception {

        X500Name subject = new X500Name("CN=\""+ID+"\",OU=\"Organizational Unit\",O=\"Organizational\",L=\"City\",ST=\"California\",C=\"US\",E=\"email@example.com\"");
        X500Name issuer = JcaX500NameUtil.getIssuer(cacert);
        int VALIDITY_PERIOD = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // one year
        Date startDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Date endDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + VALIDITY_PERIOD);
        String subjAltNameURI = "http://example.com";
        BigInteger serialNumber = BigInteger.valueOf(1000);

        PublicKey caPubKey = cacert.getPublicKey();
        NetscapeCertRequest netscapeCertReq = new NetscapeCertRequest(Base64.decode(spkacData));
        PublicKey certPubKey = netscapeCertReq.getPublicKey();

        X509v3CertificateBuilder certGenerator = new X509v3CertificateBuilder(
            issuer, 
            serialNumber, 
            startDate, 
            endDate, 
            subject, 
            SubjectPublicKeyInfo.getInstance(certPubKey.getEncoded())
        );
        // Adds the Basic Constraint (CA: false) extension.
        certGenerator.addExtension(Extension.basicConstraints, true,
            new BasicConstraints(false));

        // Adds the Key Usage extension.
        certGenerator.addExtension(Extension.keyUsage, true, new KeyUsage(
            KeyUsage.digitalSignature | KeyUsage.nonRepudiation
            | KeyUsage.keyEncipherment | KeyUsage.keyAgreement
            | KeyUsage.keyCertSign));

        // Adds the Netscape certificate type extension.
        certGenerator.addExtension(MiscObjectIdentifiers.netscapeCertType,
            false, new NetscapeCertType(NetscapeCertType.sslClient
            | NetscapeCertType.smime));

        // Adds the subject key identifier extension.
        SubjectKeyIdentifier subjectKeyIdentifier =  
            new JcaX509ExtensionUtils().createSubjectKeyIdentifier(certPubKey);
        certGenerator.addExtension(Extension.subjectKeyIdentifier, false,
            subjectKeyIdentifier);

        // Adds the subject alternative-name extension (critical).
        if (subjAltNameURI != null) {
            GeneralNames subjectAltNames = new GeneralNames(new GeneralName(
                GeneralName.uniformResourceIdentifier, subjAltNameURI));
            certGenerator.addExtension(Extension.subjectAlternativeName,
                false, subjectAltNames);
        }

        // Creates and sign this certificate with the private key corresponding
        // to the public key of the certificate 

        ContentSigner signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA1withRSA").setProvider("BC").build(caPrivKey);

        X509CertificateHolder holder = certGenerator.build(signer);
        X509Certificate cert = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider("BC").getCertificate(holder);

        // Checks that this certificate has indeed been correctly signed.
        cert.verify(caPubKey);

        return cert;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

OK I found a working answers.  I used ProcessBuilder with openssl, and generated the the client keys with HTML tag "keygen".  I got the idea from 
http://www.scriptjunkie.us/2013/11/adding-easy-ssl-client-authentication-to-any-webapp/
This example makes v1 SSL cert I'll take a look into how to do it with v3 next.

```
class RunProcessBuilder {
    public File path;
    public PrintWriter out;
    public RunProcessBuilder(File p, PrintWriter o) throws Exception {
        path = p;
        out = o;
    }
    public void Run(String args[]) throws Exception {
        out.printf("Output of running %s is:",Arrays.toString(args));
        out.flush();

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(args);
        Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
        env.put("HOME", "/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/certs/");        
        env.put("RANDFILE", "/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/certs/demoCA/.rnd");     
        pb.directory(path);
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);

        Process shell = pb.start();
        InputStream shellIn = shell.getInputStream();
        int shellExitStatus = shell.waitFor();
        int c;
        while ((c = shellIn.read()) != -1) { out.write(c); out.flush();}
        try {shellIn.close();} catch (IOException ignoreMe) { out.write(ignoreMe.toString()); out.flush();}

    }
}

public class ClientCert2 extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Example</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body bgcolor=\"white\">");

        out.println("<form method=\"post\">");
        out.println("<keygen name=\"pubkey\" challenge=\"randomchars\">");
        out.println("Username: <input type=\"text\" name=\"username\" value=\"Sam Sanders\">");
        out.println("<input type=\"submit\" name=\"createcert\" value=\"Generate\">");
        out.println("</form>");

        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");     

    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/x-x509-user-cert");

        String CN = "/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/certs/";
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(CN+"log.txt", "UTF-8");
        try {
            String ClientID = "CilentX";
            String pass = "password";
            String pubkey = request.getParameter("pubkey");
            String username = request.getParameter("username");

            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(CN+ClientID+".spkac", "UTF-8");
            writer.println("SPKAC="+pubkey.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "").replace("\t", "").replace("\0", "") );
            //.replace("\x0B", "")

            //username needs to be unique
            writer.println("CN="+username);
            writer.println("emailAddress=test@test.com");
            writer.println("0.OU=test client certificate");
            writer.println("organizationName=organizationName");
            writer.println("countryName=AU");
            writer.println("stateOrProvinceName=State");
            writer.println("localityName=City");
            writer.close();
            writer.flush();

            writer = new PrintWriter(CN+ClientID+".cnf", "UTF-8");
            writer.println("[ ca ]");
            writer.println("default_ca      = CA_default");
            writer.println("[ CA_default ]");
            writer.println("dir            = "+CN);
            writer.println("database       = "+CN+"demoCA/index.txt");
            writer.println("new_certs_dir  = "+CN+"demoCA/newcerts");
            writer.println("certificate    = "+CN+"ca.crt");
            writer.println("serial         = "+CN+"demoCA/serial");
            writer.println("private_key    = "+CN+"ca.key");
            writer.println("RANDFILE       = "+CN+"demoCA/.rnd");
            writer.println("HOME           = "+CN);
            writer.println("default_days   = 3650");
            writer.println("default_crl_days= 60");
            writer.println("default_md     = sha1");
            writer.println("policy         = policy_any");
            writer.println("email_in_dn    = yes");
            writer.println("name_opt       = ca_default");
            writer.println("cert_opt       = ca_default");
            writer.println("copy_extensions = none");
            writer.println("[ policy_any ]");
            writer.println("countryName            = supplied");
            writer.println("stateOrProvinceName    = optional");
            writer.println("organizationName       = optional");
            writer.println("organizationalUnitName = optional");
            writer.println("commonName             = supplied");
            writer.println("emailAddress           = optional");
            writer.close();
            writer.flush();

            RunProcessBuilder x = new RunProcessBuilder(new File(CN), out);
            x.Run(new String[] {"openssl","ca","-config",CN+ClientID+".cnf","-days","365","-notext","-batch","-spkac",CN+ClientID+".spkac","-passin","pass:"+pass,"-out",CN+ClientID+".crt"});

            InputStream is=new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(CN+ClientID+".crt")));
            OutputStream os=response.getOutputStream();
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            for (int nChunk = is.read(buf); nChunk!=-1; nChunk = is.read(buf)) {
                os.write(buf, 0, nChunk);
            } 
            os.close();
            os.flush();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace(out);
        }
        out.close();
        out.flush();
    }

}
```

Comment: See my comments. The entire technique is radically insecure.

Comment: But the Private key is generated on the web browser, and the server never see it.  What am I missing?